# How to calculate price from two different dates and times in php

Tags: php, price

I want to calculate the price from two different dates and times i.e

```
$price = 20;
$tripStart = "2018-02-09";
$tripEnd = "2018-02-12";
$tripStartTime = "09:00:00";
$tripStartEnd = "19:00:00";
```

I want to calculate the dates but how can I calculate the dates with time.

Currently i am calculating the date.

```
$date1 = new DateTime($tripStart);
$date2 = new DateTime(  $tripEnd  );
$days = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Its working fine but I want to calculate the dates with time.

Comment: What do you mean dates with time? Day between $tripStart and $tripEnd?

Comment: I think he means with hours, minutes & seconds

Comment: I want to calculate the total hours from above dates and time so can generate the invoice.

Comment: #Phil I want to calculate the hours so i can multiply with $price

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate exact timestamps and do it

```
$start_dt = strtotime($tripStart + " " + $tripStartTime);
$end_dt = strtotime($tripEnd + " " + $tripStartEnd);

# 86400 is number of seconds in days
$exact_duration_in_days = ($end_dt - $start_dt)/86400;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple concat your start date time and end time and do this :

```
    <?php
$tripStart = "2018-02-09";
$tripEnd = "2018-02-12";
$tripStartTime = "09:00:00";
$tripStartEnd = "19:00:00";

$start_date = new DateTime($tripStart ." ".$tripStartTime );
$end_date = new DateTime($tripEnd ." ".$tripStartEnd );
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
print_r($interval);
echo "Result " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
echo $interval->h." hours ";
?>
```

Comment: how can i calculate the hours so i can easily multiple with date

Comment: I want to generate the invoice against these dates and time the price is:  $price = 20;